# android listview nothing is getting printed on the list

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I tried the example given in this link http://mfarhan133.wordpress.com/2010/10/14/list-view-tutorial-for-android/. I have the exact code as his, but nothing is getting printed in my listview.

Please someone help.

Comment: -1 should have comment too. So +1ing it to negate it.
@mad_programmer, where are you running it, which version of android. give more info. just a link is not sufficient for a question.

Comment: How are we supposed to help you with this little information?

Comment: @ghostCoder its google api 1.5 api 3.

Comment: @Phlibbo I am sorry, but the code is exactly the same as in the link.

Comment: You have to do some debugging yourself, nobody will go through the whole code and guess what might be wrong in your case.

Comment: dude..i did debuggin myself..but couldnt get anything..thats why i came up here.

Comment: If you did some debugging, please provide details. What exactly did you check, what are the results? Did you limit the error space to certain code parts? If not, why? And so on ..

Comment: And I just ran that code. Works for me. Chances that your code isn't the exact one from the link are pretty high.

Answer (score 1):

If you donnload the whole source code then you will see in the Manifest:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />
```

Since you are using level 3 that is maybe the problem. Why use 1.5? it's very old most phones use 2.1 or 2.2 nowadays

Comment: @alextsc thanks but I had to use google maps thats why I opted for google api 1.5.

Comment: That's not my answer, i just edited it since the xml tag was invisible without codetags. Thank vallllll. :)